# Adding controls to view from viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to make a simple task manager as way to learn prism and MVVM in WPF applications.

Currently I have a MainWindow and MainWindowViewModel, a TaskList and TaskListViewModel, and a Task and TaskViewModel.

When I load the application I have 1 button "new task" The end goal is to click the "new task" button and then have it add a new "task" to the "task list", however I can't seem to figure out how to add the control from the MainWindowViewModel.

MainWindowViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Commands;
using WpfApplication3.Views;

namespace WpfApplication3.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public DelegateCommand NewTask { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            NewTask = new DelegateCommand(Execute);
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Worked");

        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.Views" x:Class="WpfApplication3.Views.MainWindow"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="177*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="340*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button Grid.Row="0" x:Name="btnNew" Content="New Task" Command="{Binding NewTask}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="taskList" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"/>
        <local1:TaskList HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

TaskList XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.Views.TaskList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="177">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Task XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.Views.Task"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.Views"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="177">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Question:

How can I dynamically add the "Task" user control, to the "Task List" usercontrol and keep the MVVM, without adding Code Behind on the MainWindow View?

My immediate thought is that I need to go through the ViewModel, but I can't seem to get the MainWindowViewModel to see the View Objects (Nor am I sure that it *should*)

Comment: I hope your can look into ItemTemplate of listbox control. Where you can hook a datatemplate with UserControl.

Comment: What is the purpose of TaskList and Task View? Is task view for DataEntry from the user?

Comment: Well i'm new to WPF and Prism, so I might just not understand the correct way to do this. The purpose of TaskList control is to hold the "task" control which will load the details of the task into another section. So when you click a task, it loads the details of the task for the user to see.

Comment: I see you are new to wpf but I like your thinking. Keep going, you'll rock ;)

Answer (score 4):

Created a small sample for you. Have a look at it.

```
<Window x:Class="ChkList_Learning.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList}" x:Name="taskList">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskId}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text=" - "></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskName}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="ID"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding ElementName=taskList,Path=SelectedItem.TaskId}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Song Name"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Width="100"  Text="{Binding ElementName=taskList,Path=SelectedItem.TaskName}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new TaskViewModel();
    }
}


class TaskViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Task> TaskList { get; set; }

    public TaskViewModel()
    {
        TaskList = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Task task = new Task();
            task.TaskId = (i + 1).ToString();
            task.TaskName = "Task Name" + (i + 1).ToString();
            TaskList.Add(task);
        }
    }
}

class Task
{
    public string TaskId { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Two comments here: 1. your naming convention may be confusing, since he names viewmodels after view (MainWindow - MainWindowViewModel), which is recommended. He has a view called Task -> you made a model from it. 2. What's the purpose of your taskviewmodel, when you databind selected item to listbox, rather viewmodel property?

Answer (score 1):

TaskList and TaskListViewModel classes are absolutely redundant here.

Just create property

```
public ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel> Tasks {get;}
```

in MainWindowViewModel

and databind it to ListBox or ItemsControl in MainWindow.xaml

When you add an item to Tasks collection, wpf automatically adds ListBoxItem to ListBox or ItemsControl for you. Now, all you need to display your Task controls inside ListBox is to set ItemTemplate

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList}" x:Name="taskList">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:Task />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but where is the TaskList binding coming from if I am replacing the taskList view because of redundancy (Which I agree, that felt weird.)

Comment: So when I try to add something to the Tasks collection, it's now saying that the Tasks collection is null.